# Where statement where the user's average minutes is greater than or equal to the overall average minutes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What I'm trying to do is write a select statement to show a technician_name column and an average_minutes_per_ticket column. But I want to narrow the results down to technicians who have an average greater than or equal to the overall average minutes per ticket. Below is what I have so far.

```
select user_firstname + ' ' + user_lastname as technician_name, 
  avg(ticket_request_date - ticket_closeddate) as average_minutes_per_ticket
  from hd_users
    join hd_tickets on ticket_requestor_id=user_id
  where user_is_technician = ‘Yes’ and
    average_minutes_per_ticket >= ???
```

Comment: To use aggregate functions in where condition you need to use **Having** keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close! If you want to have a predicate (where) clause on an aggregate (like avg), you need to use the `HAVING` clause. In that clause, you can compare it to the overall avg in a subquery.

```
  select user_firstname + ' ' + user_lastname as technician_name, 
    avg(ticket_request_date - ticket_closeddate) as average_minutes_per_ticket
  from hd_users
    join hd_tickets on ticket_requestor_id=user_id
  where user_is_technician = ‘Yes’ 
  having
    avg(ticket_request_date - ticket_closeddate) >= (
         select avg(ticket_request_date - ticket_closeddate) from hd_users)
```